# Creating a table per user in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database-design

I'm very new to all this...and for a project work in my college I have decided to make an online shopping website.

I am stuck at the sign up part.
I wanted the users to have a separated table for themselves that allow them to store the products that they have added in their cart so that they can keep adding more products later as well.

But as I read in other questions in all your links, creating a table per user seems to be a very bad idea.

but otherwise how can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me explain in detail.

I guess you have already created table for user and product. if not then you need to create table for user and product with unique value of user_id and product_id respectively.

Now create user_shopping cart table with following fields

- user_id
- product_id
- product_qty

You can update user_shopping as per you need.

Comment: @nDudani..
yes i have already created a table named user.but i have made different table for different types of products.Can we link them as well?

Comment: Again it's not good Idea, I suggest add field name "type" in product table.

Comment: but its too late..the submission date is veryy near.So i wont be able to make changes in all  the tables and all the code.
Could you give me some ideas for the sign up and adding the product to cart so that the user can view it next time??

Comment: how many table you have for products?

Comment: 4 tables for diff kind of products..
actually what i wanted to do was...
make a table with product_name and qty in it.
and whenever a user signs up a table is created for him.
and everything he selects is stored into his table so that he can access it next time.

Comment: you can use union for selecting product data from your various product table.

Answer (score 2):

Make ***one*** table that contains the columns `user_id` and `product_id`.
That way you can associate products with users without needing a table for each user.

Comment: could you please explain how can i do that?
And if possible with the code..
THANK YOU..:)